# Doors will not lock

Tags: chevrolet, audio, central-locking, colorado

I replaced the factory radio in my 2005 Colorado with a aftermarket radio. The radio works great. The power door locks stopped working, on the doors and the fob. What did I do wrong?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: First off, have you checked the electrics for shorts, blown fuses, correct voltages etc?